# What is the disadvantage of custom thread pool?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

Compared to custom thread pool, [source](https://www.baeldung.com/java-when-to-use-parallel-stream) which refers to Oracle documentation recommends using common thread pool when parallel streaming.

Since the common pool has same number of threads with the number of CPU cores what's the difference between using a common thread pool and custom thread pool which consists of same number of threads with the common pool?

Comment: No difference at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what's the difference between using a common thread pool and custom thread pool which consists of same number of threads with the common pool?

Some important considerations:

1. With the common thread pool, you don't need to write or maintain or configure or manage your own thread pool.
2. The common thread pool exists and is used, and it already provides as many threads as there are cores.  No more threads than that can make progress at the same time anyway, so if you set up a custom pool and it and the common one are both fully subscribed for non-blocking operations then you incur additional overhead from the additional threads but no speedup.

Comment: It is important to know that you can't specify the number of threads in a ForkJoinPool. You can only set the parallelism level. ForkJoinPool is free to create many more threads to ensure that the target parallelism level is reached.

Answer (score 2):

It might be better to ask, what is the advantage of a custom thread pool? It's more work, so why do it?

Processors are a global resource. Custom thread pools can be created in different places without any coordination, and thus "over-allocate" the processors.

A re-usable library should not create custom thread pools; if you can justify why a custom thread pool is desirable, it should be managed at a higher level in the application. To support this, a re-usable library might permit a caller to configure (inject) a custom executor, and fall back to the common thread pool by default.

Comment: Another reason for not simply using the default thread pool would be if the application had different thread pools for different categories of task. One especially useful category would be satisfied by a "single thread" executor: That is, an `ExecutorService` which performs the given tasks "in the background," but which also guarantees to execute them sequentially, and in the order they were submitted.